# How can I see the data or tables of my mdf file in server sql (the mdf has been already attached?

Tags: sql-server, database

I know this is one of the stupidest questions ever asked...
basically I have been able to attach my database in microsoft sql server studio...
Now I would like to see really the data or tables like in excel by instance... 
I am newbie with server sql and databases and I am sure someone else has made the same question again...but I have not been able to find it on the web and previous questions.
any suggestion, please?

Comment: Can you see option of Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio? are you aware about SQL Scripts. if yes then write SQL Statements mate.

Comment: yes I can see the options of Object Explorer and i can see my database in databases. So I believe that i have to study a bit of statements...but i don't know the content of my database...i have only seen by using `sys.table` that there are 25 tables...Now I would like to see these tables one by one...but i have to learn first statements

Comment: Yes! it will benefit you!